# Write a matrix in terms of a other matrix

Tags: matrices

Let $M:=(m_{ij})_{i,j=1,...,n}$ be a matrix. If there is a matrix $N:=(m_{ij}^l)_{i,j=1,...,n}$, $l\in\mathbb{N}$, is there any option to write $N$ in terms of $M$? Something like $N=M^{l}$?

Comment: If $M$ is diagonal, sure. But otherwise, no.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. $M$ is not diagonal.

Comment: *(…) is there any option to write $N$ in terms of $M$ (…)* is a vague question. What is your question background? Where is the problem coming from?